# How to get a certain bytes length subString from a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, byte, string-length

Such as I have a `NSString` is `str = @"我就是测试一下"` or `str = @"我"` . And I want to restrict a certain byte length. such as `byteLength = 10`.

I know the subSrtring is not the `str.length=10` How to get a certain bytes length subString from a NSString, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `dataUsingEncoding` method to get a `NSData` from `NSString`. And then use `length` and `bytes` property to get the `byte length` or `bytes`

Then if the `NSData's length > your certain length` you should use `+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length;` method to get the certain length byte `NSData` you should be careful that the return `NSData` may be can not decode by `NSString`

At last you can use `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` method to get the result `NSString` you want

And you can use the code below:

```
- (NSString *)fetchStringWithOriginalString:(NSString *)originalString withByteLength:(NSUInteger)length
{
    NSData* originalData=[originalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *originalBytes = originalData.bytes;

    //make sure to use a loop to get a not nil string.
    //because your certain length data may be not decode by NSString
    for (NSUInteger i = length; i > 0; i--) {

        @autoreleasepool {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:originalBytes length:i];
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if (string) {
                return string;
            }
        }

    }
    return @"";
}
```

you can call the above method like this :

```
NSString* originalString= @"我就是测试一下";
NSString *string = [self fetchStringWithOriginalString:originalString withByteLength:10];
NSData* stringData=[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"10 bytes string : %@ ; it only %i bytes",string,stringData.length);
```

The Result : 
[image]

Be careful:
the `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` may be return `nil`

As apple said:the `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` Return:

> An NSString object initialized by converting the bytes in data into
>   Unicode characters using encoding. The returned object may be
>   different from the original receiver. Returns nil if the
>   initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not
>   represent valid data for encoding).

So you should use a for loop to get a nearest length data which can decode by `NSSting`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
NSUInteger bytes = [incomingText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (bytes > MAX_TEXT_BYTES) {
    int length = [incomingText length];
    int cutoffIndex = (int)(MAX_TEXT_BYTES * (length / bytes));
    return [incomingText substringToIndex:cutoffIndex];
}
```